# What is the purpose of "use <classname>;" in PHP?

Tags: php, import, namespaces

What is the point of the `use` keyword, as in `use FooInterface;` from [below code](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md)?

```
namespace Vendor\Package;

use FooInterface;
use BarClass as Bar;
use OtherVendor\OtherPackage\BazClass;

class Foo extends Bar implements FooInterface
{
    public function sampleFunction($a, $b = null)
    {
        if ($a === $b) {
            bar();
        } elseif ($a > $b) {
            $foo->bar($arg1);
        } else {
            BazClass::bar($arg2, $arg3);
        }
    }

    final public static function bar()
    {
        // method body
    }
}
```

Isn't that just superfluous?

Comment: I think it's main function in that context is to explicitly state a dependency to another developer... functionally I don't believe it brings anything to the table. Not sure though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without that clause your code would look like this:

```
class Foo extends Bar implements \FooInterface
                                 ^
```

Notice the leading backslash? It's required because you're in the `Vendor\Package` namespace, so any references to the global namespace must start with a `\` unless it's imported.

This is also explained in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php).